# is there a way to call a method or sub from an user control to a different user control without instantiating?

Tags: vb.net

I have a user control called Search and a method called TimeExpired as shown in the below code snippet

```
Public Class Search
   Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

     Private Sub TimeExpired()
       MsgBox("time is expired")
     end sub
 End Class
```

Now, I would like to call/invoke TimeExpired method in another user control called "Activity" which is in different project , how to do this without instantiating search user control?

Thanks,
Addy

Comment: Make it a `Public Shared` method.

Comment: @JQSOFT, making shared will not work if both user control is in different project. I know that I can implement this using raisevent but I need other way to achieve this if we have any.

Comment: @JQSPFT, yes both are in same solution.

Comment: It's hard to say what you're actually trying to achieve based on your description but it is undoubtedly misguided.  Your design needs a rethink.  If you think that you want to call a method in a control with instantiating the control then the method almost certainly shouldn't be in that control.